# From List of an object to Group objects with its key and values based on Java 8 or Guava

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, guava

I am looking forward to converting a list to a map

`List<Element>` to a map of `Map<String,List<Element>`

**Element** class contains **keys and values**

```
public class Element  {

 public Element(final key, final value) {
        this((Object) key, (Object) value, 1L);
    }
public final Object getObjectKey() {
        return key;
    }
 public final Object getObjectValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The way i add Elements is like

```
empRepository.save(new Element(empKey, empTransaction));
```

The empKey is an object of class EmpKey

```
public class EmpKey{

private String employeeId;
private String tenantId;
//Getters & Setters
}
```

In Another class the method groupElementsByEmployeeId trying to convert those Collection elements parameter to a map

```
public void groupElementsByEmployeeId(Collection<Element> elements){

List<Element> to a map of Map<String,List<Element>

 where Map key String is tenantId which is in EmpKey

}
```

To group all the Elements based on tenantId Which is a property of EmpKey

EmpKey is the Key for Element

```
//List<Element> to a map of Map<String,List<Element>

// where Map key String is tenantId which is in EmpKey
```

Something i started , but dont know how to get the output i am looking for

```
elements.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Element::getObjectKey))

I have to cast groupingBy(Element::(EmpKey)getObjectKey.getTenantId))
```

Comment: As you already think about using Guava replace `Map<String,List<Element>` with one of Guava's [`ListMultimap<Key, Value>`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/17.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) implementations.

Comment: I finished reading your "question" - however I am missing what you are asking for. Please edit it and add what is your problem.

Comment: How I can do the grouping because the key for map is tenantId which is an attribute for EmpKey . EmpKey is the key for Element

Comment: @Robert I did some editing on my question , and what i am trying for

Comment: I am looking to do that in decent coding standards, save is a requirement to do that in a way. It's a part of Ehcache I Just edited to simplify

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are near. I would just do:

```
Map<String, List<Element>> map = elements.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> ((EmpKey) e.getObjectKey()).getTenantId()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You really want to use `Multimap` (more specifically [`ListMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html)) here. It's basically a map of keys to collection of values, for more detailed description please read [this wiki page](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap).

In your case you could use [`Multimaps.index`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Function-) method which does exactly what you want:

```
ListMultimap<String, Element> multimap =
    Multimaps.index(elements, e -> ((EmpKey) e.getObjectKey()).getTenantId());

// get your elements under a key:
List<Element> elements = multimap.get("someTenantId");

// view Multimap as plain Map
Map<String, Collection<Element>> mapOfCollections = multimap.asMap();
Map<String, List<Element>> mapOfLists = Multimaps.asMap(multimap);
```

Without using Guava, you could use [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-), see Federico Peralta Schaffner's answer.